# Part time job at the vegetable/fruits shop.

Tags: sequences-and-series

You recently applied for a job at the vegetable/fruits store and the shop owner called you for a small quiz.so you went there and everything was going apparently well… but then he asked you that since his favourite number is 10 and his favourite fruit is orange so he wants to make a pyramid of oranges where the triangle on the base is an equilateral triangle made having 10 oranges on each side, then the total number of oranges in the complete pyramid will be??

Note-this is a homework question from sequences and series  and not something I picked from a puzzle book… I tried solving it but I am not able to visualise it properly so I am not able to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangle on base will have (1 + 2 + 3 + 4+ ... +10)
Next one will have as above but only to 9 - and so on until you only have 1 at the top
I have deliberately not done the entire calculation for you - if you are still confused after this attempt to help you visualize it, add a comment and I will clarify more

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I visualise it. Triangle on base will have ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 ) oranges and the next one will have ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 ).

So the total amount will be : 10*1 + 9*2 + 8*3 + 7*4 + 6*5 + 5*6 + 4*7 + 3*8 + 2*9 + 1*10